# how to store more values in option tag under select tag

Tags: html, jsp

i am doing dynamic web project in Eclipse

i am using dropdown list in my jsp page with with multiple <option> tag

for example

```
<select>
  <option name="o1" value="abc">abc</option>
  <option name="o2" value="xyz">xyz</option>
</select>
```

but i need store more than one value for each option 
so there is any solution..??

i need if user select first option 
i require more than 1 value for the option

means --> user select abc --> i get name=o1 value=abc externalLink=true/false has parent=yes/no

i need 4 different values when user select that option 
so there is any solution for that or any alternative are available in jsp for do that task...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the new data-tag like:

```
 <option name="o2" value="xyz" data-external="true" data-parent="yes">xyz</option>
```

Comment: hay ok i will try that code,
how can i get that data-tag value in servlet
for example i want value i write request.getparameter("o2");
so i will get it's value 
but how can i get data-tag value..??

Comment: No problem, if you were to use jquery they got a nifty feature where you can use $(element).data('nameOfData');

Comment: hay friend i am testing data-tag it good work in fireFox and IE ,but ie will not work in chrome..

Comment: ok..
i was checked your link that work in chrome...
may be there is some other problem in chrome..

Comment: Here i did one in pure JS as well: http://jsfiddle.net/MzzL8/3/ so i think maybe the problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: There is problem in my <option> tag 
i am call function like
<option data-link-"b1" onclick=getVal(this)>opt1</option>
onclick attribute work on ie and firefox and not work in chrome....

Comment: but i got solution...for that problem...:)

Answer (score -1):

You could make the other parameters hidden values and when the selection is chosen, you could use the onchange event to adjust their values like this:

```
<script>
function setOtherFields(ext,par) {
  document.getElementById("hid_ext").value = ext;
  document.getElementById("hid_par").value = par;
}
</script>
<input type="hidden" name="externalLink" id="hid_ext" value="link1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="parent" id="hid_par" value="yes"/>
<select>
  <option name="o1" value="abc" onchange="setOtherFields('link1','yes')">abc</option>
  <option name="o2" value="xyz" onchange="setOtherFields('link2','no')">xyz</option>
</select>
```

Just set the initial 'values' to match what you want with the initial selection so it will be correct if no change is made.

Comment: onchange event not firing